# Using multiple GPU's in Ubuntu 16?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu, motherboard, resource-limiting

I have a question I have been researching for days on.  I have a MSI z97 gaming 5 board with 7 PCI slots.  All the slots work fine for GPU's as I have an identical board with 7 AMD GPU's running.  The other board I have 7 NVidia cards, GTX 1060 3GB.  With 6 cards this board runs fine, when I put in the 7th, I can see it when I do a `lspci -v` I can see all 7 NVidia cards.  Here is a difference between a working card and non working card.

Output from a working card:

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c02 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])           
       Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 85b1 
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31 
       Memory at f4000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M] 
       Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M] 
       Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M] 
       I/O ports at d000 [size=128] 
       [virtual] Expansion ROM at f5000000 [disabled] [size=512K] 
       Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3 
       Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+ 
       Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00 
       Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel 
       Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting 
       Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting  
       Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting 
       Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024                                  
       Capabilities: [900] #19 
       Kernel driver in use: nvidia 
       Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Here is the output from the non-working 7th card:

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c02 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])           
       Subsystem: Device 196e:11d9            
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32        
       Memory at f2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M] 
       Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]    
       Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]     
       I/O ports at c000 [size=128]        
       [virtual] Expansion ROM at f3000000 [disabled] [size=512K] 
       Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3 
       Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+ 
       Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00 
       Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel 
       Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting 
       Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting  
       Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting 
       Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024  
       Capabilities: [900] #19 
       Kernel driver in use: nvidia 
       Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

```
[/root]:# lsdev
Device            DMA   IRQ  I/O Ports
------------------------------------------------
0000:00:1f.3                   f000-f01f
0000:01:00.0                     e000-e07f
0000:02:00.0                     d000-d07f
0000:03:00.0                     c000-c07f
0000:05:00.0                     b000-b07f
0000:06:00.0                     a000-a07f
0000:07:00.0                     9000-907f
0000:08:00.0                     8000-807f
0000:09:00.0                     7000-707f
ACPI                           1800-1803   1804-1805   1808-180b   1820-182f   1850-1850
acpi                      9 
cascade             4       
dma                            0080-008f
dma1                           0000-001f
dma2                           00c0-00df
ehci_hcd:usb1            16 
ehci_hcd:usb2            23 
eth0                     29 
fpu                            00f0-00ff
i8042                  1 12 
iTCO_wdt.0.auto                1830-1833   1860-187f
keyboard                       0060-0060   0064-0064
mei_me                   28 
nvidia                30 31 32 33 34 35 
PCI                          0000-0cf7 0cf8-0cff 0d00-ffff   7000-7fff   8000-8fff   9000-9fff   a000-afff   b000-bfff   c000-cfff   d000-dfff   e000-efff
pic1                           0020-0021
pic2                           00a0-00a1
pnp                            04d0-04d1   0800-087f   0a00-0a1f   0a20-0a2f   0a30-0a3f   1854-1857
PNP0C04:00                       00f0-00f0
rtc0                      8    0070-0077
serial                         03f8-03ff
timer                     0 
timer0                         0040-0043
timer1                         0050-0053
vga+                           03c0-03df
xhci_hcd                 27
```

The Subsystem: Device ID is what seems to jump out at me the most.  So the board sees it but cannot give enough resources to use it?

Any chance someone knows what I can do to get this card working?

Comment: What did you end up doing? Were you able to get it working?